# PHP json_encode multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
array (size=6)
  'company' => 
    array (size=1)
      99 => string 'eeeeee'
  'Naam' => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string 'werwerew'
  'phone' => 
    array (size=1)
      4 => string 'ewrwerwer'
  'email' => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => string 'test@test.com'
```

Can I get json_encode output of this array something like this?

```
{"company":"eeeeee":"99","Naam":"werwerew":"1","phone":"ewrwerwer":"4","email":"test@test.com":"3","mesaj":"werewrewr":"0"}
```

Currently I json_encode the array and the output is this:

```
{"company":{"99":"eeeeee"},"Naam":{"1":"werwerew"},"phone":{"4":"ewrwerwer"},"email":{"3":"test@test.com"},"mesaj":{"0":"werewrewr"}}
```

and is not what I want.

Comment: Well that wouldn't be valid JSON anymore, so I wouldn't try to do that.

Comment: You will have to change your array structure in order to get the expected outcome.

Comment: Your desired structure is NOT valid JSON. You can not have a item like this one: `"Naam":"werwerew":"1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are looking for is not valid JSON. If your aim is to have a result that does not have nested braces, then first *unnest* your source array structure:

```
// sample data
$data = array (
  'company' => array("99" => 'eeeeee'),
  'Naam' => array ("1" => 'werwerew'),
  'phone' => array ("4" => 'ewrwerwer'),
  'email' =>  array ("3" => 'test@test.com')
);  

// unnest array, assuming inner level arrays only have one key/value pair:
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $result[$key . ":" . current($row)] = "" . key($row);
}

// Now convert that flat array to JSON
$json = json_encode($result);
```

*$json* will have this value:

```
{"company:eeeeee":"99","Naam:werwerew":"1","phone:ewrwerwer":"4","email:test@test.com":"3"}
```

Note that this is valid JSON, as here the first colon is part of the key name.

If you prefer the numbers not to have double quotes around them, then remove the `"" .` part from the loop, to get this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $result[$key . ":" . current($row)] = key($row);
}
```

*$json* will then get this value:

```
{"company:eeeeee":99,"Naam:werwerew":1,"phone:ewrwerwer":4,"email:test@test.com":3}
```